# Tableview Empty and want to use backgroundView to post a message

Tags: ios, swift

I just want to show a message in the middle of the screen when the tableview is empty.  The following code works fine on the simulator but on my phone it doesn't show the message.  I'm stumped as to why the difference.  I am using the iPhone 11 (13.5) simulator and mine is iPhone X (original one) running 13.5.1 just updated.

```
func EmptyMessage(shows: String) {
        print("Found nothing")
        let noDataFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height)
        let noData: UILabel = UILabel(frame: noDataFrame)
        noData.text = shows
        noData.textColor = .black
        noData.numberOfLines = 0
        noData.textAlignment = .center
        //noData.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        noData.sizeToFit()
        tableView.backgroundView = noData
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }
```

In this particular app, I only have the one section. So called from...

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
    let numOfSectons: Int = 1;

    if let _ = aircraftResults?.count, aircraftResults!.count > 0 {
        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
        print("Found something")
    } else{
        EmptyMessage(shows: "No Aircraft Defined!")
    }
    return numOfSectons
```

}

What am I missing on my iPhone running 13.5.1

Thanks in advance...
Scott

Comment: Use the `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method as opposed to `numberOfSections`.

Comment: Thanks also to you El Tomato...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if let aircraftResultsCount = aircraftResults?.count, aircraftResultsCount > 0 {
        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
        return aircraftResultsCount
    } else {
        EmptyMessage(shows: "No Aircraft Defined!")
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, now I feel stupid...  I had set the textColor to black as you can see above and using my phone in dark mode.  So it was there but couldn't see the text!  I discovered this because the line separator was gone when no aircraft so the view HAD to be there.  Once I added noData.backgroundColor = .red, the text showed up.  The simulator was not in dark mode so it showed all the time fine.   Geez...  My bad and thanks...